# Unity Interception MethodSignatureMatchingRule could not be resolved

Tags: unity-container, enterprise-library, unity-interception, cross-cutting-concerns

Im using Unity (3.0) interception to add some crosscutting concerns to my application. Somehow I **can't use the MethodSignatureMatchingRule** in my configuration getting this error message:

```
{"The type name or alias MethodSignatureMatchingRule could not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name."}
```

My configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
  <sectionExtension type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.Configuration.InterceptionConfigurationExtension, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception.Configuration" />
  <alias alias="singleton" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ContainerControlledLifetimeManager, Microsoft.Practices.Unity" />
  <containers>
    <container name="MyContainer">
      <extension type="Interception"/>
      <interception>
        <policy name="EhabAspect">
          <matchingRule name="MethodSignatureMatchingRule" type="MethodSignatureMatchingRule">
            <constructor>
              <param name="methodName" value="Receive" type="string"/>
            </constructor>
          </matchingRule>
          <callHandler ... (omitted)
        </policy>
      </interception>
      <register type="IMyClass" mapTo="MyClass">
        <lifetime type="singleton" />
        <interceptor type="InterfaceInterceptor"/>
        <policyInjection/>
      </register>
    </container>
  </containers>
</unity>
```

The same configuration with the **NamespaceMatchingRule works fine.**

My assembly contains a reference to

- Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common
- Microsoft.Practices.Unity
- Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try specifying the full qualified name of MethodSignatureMatchingRule type?

Comment: Not yet. But the alias for the MethodSignatureMatchingRule should be already registred by the Interception extension. I will try it and update my question if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same problem here. I solved using the full qualified name of the of the class.

```
<matchingRule name="AuthorizationMethod" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.MethodSignatureMatchingRule, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception">
  <constructor>
    <param name="methodName" value="Authenticate" type="string"/>
    <param name="parameterTypeNames" dependencyName="EmptyArray"/>
  </constructor>
</matchingRule>
```